# Best way to display an error Express, Jade and Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

What is the best way to pass a warning message through to a view with Express & Jade?

I have created a login system that checks a password entered against one stored within the Mongo Database, it then sets a cookie and redirects, or just redirects if it's incorrect.

```
if(obj.password === req.body.loginPassword){
     res.cookie('username', req.body.loginUsername);
     red.redirect('/')
}else{
     res.redirect('/');
}
```

I'd like to pass a warning message via the else on a failed login to the view.

Answer (score 3):

**Express 3.0:**

You can use req.session to store the error message or check out this middleware for simple:
https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash

**Express 2.0:**

You can use req.flash directly. The usage described in http://expressjs.com/2x/guide.html